# Is RedisTimeSeries free or open source?

Tags: redis

I'm confused trying to figure out whether RedisTimeSeries is free or not. I saw it is open source, but i also saw something there is rate limit. So i am very confused. Could I setup RedisTimeSeries on my own cluster without paying or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RedisTimeSeries is source available and licenced under `Redis Source Available License` ([RSAL](https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries/blob/master/LICENSE)).  This license is permissive if your product is not a "database product".  The definition of "database product" is within the license. There is no such thing as a "rate limit" for RedisTimeSeries, at least not with regards to the license.

Disclaimer: I am at the time of writing Product Manager at Redis Inc.

Comment: Ehm... So do you mean i could set up a Redistimeseries database on a cluster without rate limit without paying Redis? For example, are we allowed using Redistimeseriesdb for financial analysis across 2 clusters?

Comment: Without rate limit: yes, there is no rate limit.  Please share where you got this information of "rate limit" from.  
For your product/use case, please consult the definition of "database product" in the license.  With the information you shared, it sounds like it's not a "database product", but I can't confirm that with the limited information your shared.

Comment: Thanks! I will find out where I got the "rate limit impression", I had another question, would there be significance performance difference if i run with Docker or build my own? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: Since version 1.8, RedisTimeSeries is licensed under the Redis Source Available License 2.0 ([RSALv2](https://redis.io/docs/stack/license/#redis-source-available-license-rsal-20)) or the Server Side Public License v1 ([SSPLv1](https://www.mongodb.com/licensing/server-side-public-license)).